# RadComboBox is not displaying image

Tags: webforms, telerik, asp.net-ajax

I have a custom RadComboBox with an image bound to it. It is not displaying the image, it's displaying the path to the image file in text.

```
 public IDictionary<string, object> Attributes
    {
        get
        {
            //Fix for XT-2253
            _attributes["DisplayStatusType"] =string.Format(null, "<div class=\"bed_priority_field\"><img src=\"../img/assignment_{0}.png\" /></div>","priority");

            _attributes["Tooltip"] = Tooltip;
            return _attributes;
        }
    }
```

How do I get it to display the image instead of the text?

Answer (score 0):

You should use Templates in this case. 
Check this online demo on how to do it:
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/functionality/templates/defaultcs.aspx